# Test client won't PXE boot anymore black screen

Tags: windows, dell, pxe-boot, mdt

So today i wanted to have an Task Sequence only for programs to install, so i chose Post OS Installation Task Sequence and i did nothing about it and when i wanted to try and deploy an application it gave me an error message saying i need to remove any usb and other drives so i did remove my usb and continued

now i restarted my test client i chose my boot.wim and made it to the screen where you see Microsoft Deployment Tool in the right corner and i see a pop-up quickly appearing and disappearing and after a couple seconds i just get a black screen and all of the sudden the client desides to restart.

**What i have tried is:**

Removing the Task Sequence and rebuilded MDT from the base up (second option) and replaced the old boot.wim files with the new boot.wim files (x86 & x64).

restarted the WDS service.

restarted the server itself.

tried to PXE boot on a another client and there it works just fine, where i can choose the task sequences etc.

Does anyone have an idea and where i must look?

i also have looked on this forum if i can find something that is related with me, but no one seems to have had this problem.

Thanks in advance!
Stef

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have an idea and where i must look?

Missing or bad drivers for the affected client...